# Create default VPC with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Using AWS cli, creating a default VPC is pretty simple:

```
aws ec2 create-default-vpc
```

How do I do the same with cloudformation?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a VPC using AWS CloudFormation? Or are you specifically asking how to create a **default** VPC with CloudFormation? Note that each Region can only have _one_ default VPC and it is rare you would need to recreate them.

Comment: I am asking how to create the default one with CloudFormation. I am in an environment where people receive AWS accounts that have no default VPC. So it is not the standard AWS scenario where I believe by default you get a default VPC. I don't want to custom cook my own VPC.

Comment: I _suspect_ that you can't create a Default VPC via CloudFormation. If you really need it, then you could create a Custom Resource in CloudFormation that runs an AWS Lambda function that calls this API.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Thus you would have to create such a resource in the form of a lambda function. The function would use AWS SDK (e.g. boto3) to create a default VPC.